# Accumulation point being a boundary point

Tags: real-analysis

Show that every accumulation point of a set that does not itself belong to the set must be a boundary point of the set.

Comment: why you cannot prove this yourself? no disparaging but this is elementary enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the set $S$. Denote this accumulation point as $p \not\in S$. Every neighborhood around $p$ contains a point of $S$ (because it's an accumulation point of $S$) and a point not in $S$ (namely, itself).

Therefore, $p$ is in the boundary of $S$. QED.

Of course, your proof will look different depending on the version of 'boundary' you're using. I was using the third definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_%28topology%29#Common_definitions).